# PHP - Quickly Loop Through Image Pixels

Tags: php, loops, optimization, ocr

Good afternoon SO Community,

I've been working on a project that calls for some optical character recognition. I am trying to keep the project light and portable, so installing third party programs won't be an option here.

Anyways, I decided to write my own OCR in PHP, but it loops through the image EXTREMELY slow. The way I'm currently doing it, is two nested for loops. I'm trying to loop through a given image (In this case, the image is a PNG. 263x55 pixels), and write the rgba to a text file. (Format: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'). The alpha is between 0 and 127 since it is using PHP.

My code works, but is very slow, and the image really isn't that large. Can you think of any way I could speed this up?

Thanks in advance,

Tim

```
<?php
// To prevent the script from timing out
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
If (isset($_GET["Image"])) {
    $pImage = $_GET["Image"];
} Else {
    $pImage = "1";
}
parseImage($pImage);

// END TEST SYSTEM

Function parseImage($ImgNum) {
    Echo "Parsing Image $ImgNum";
    $logFile = "Image$ImgNum.txt";
    $fHandle = fopen($logFile, "w");
    If ($ImgNum != 1 AND $ImgNum != 2 AND $ImgNum != 3 AND $ImgNum != 4 AND $ImgNum != 5 AND $ImgNum != 6) {
        Echo "Error: Image number is invalid.";
        Exit();
    }

    // Start Optical Character Recognition
    $Image = "https://www.example.com/img/Image$ImgNum.png";
    $size   = getimagesize($Image);
    $width  = $size[0];
    $height = $size[1];
    $ctrH = 0;
    $ctrW = 0;

    for($x=1;$x<=$width;$x++) {
        for($y=1;$y<=$height;$y++) {
            $pixel = getPixel($Image, $x, $y);
            fwrite($fHandle, $pixel . "\n");
            $ctrH ++;
        }
        $ctrW ++;
    }
    fclose($fHandle);

    Echo "Analyzing <a href='$Image'>$Image</a><br />";
    Echo $ctrW . "px wide<br />";
    Echo ($ctrH / $ctrW) . "px tall<br />";
}


function getPixel($image, $x, $y) {
    // Echo "<br />Reading $image. X: $x - Y: $y<br />";
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($image);
    $rgb = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);
    $colors = imagecolorsforindex($im, $rgb);
    $r = $colors["red"];
    $g = $colors["green"];
    $b = $colors["blue"];
    $a = $colors["alpha"];
    $print = "Pixel (" . $x . "x" . $y . "): rgba($r, $g, $b, $a)";
    return $print;
}
?>
```

Comment: Just an fyi, I think you're awesome for coding your own OCR.

Comment: @nfnneil Thanks haha!

Comment: Mad props for trying your own OCR.  Move imagecreatefrompng outside your function and outside your nested loops.  I see creating that image in memory every pixel lookup as overhead city.  Do it once and pass it around.

Comment: @SymeonQuimby First of all, thanks! Second of all, holy crap that made this SUPER fast. Please redo this in the form of an answer so I can accept it lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are creating the image every time you lookup the value of a pixel by having `imagecreatefrompng` inside your getPixel function.  Move this outside your getPixel function and nested loops, and pass it in instead.

This way you do not carry the overhead of exploding the image into memory, looking up a pixel, then having that work destroyed by the garbage collector as the function exits, only to do it all over again next pixel.

Comment: Fantastic answer. This sped up the script by a TON. Instead of it taking nearly 20 minutes to run, it only takes a few seconds lol. Makes sense haha.